# Create a vector with the sum of the positive elements of each column of a m*n numeric matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I need to create an R function which takes a numeric matrix A of arbitrary format n*m as input and returns a vector that is as long as A's number of columns that contains the sum of the positive elements of each column.

I must do this in 2 ways - the first in a nested loop and the second as a one liner using vector/matrix operations.

So far I have come up with the following code which creates the vector the size of the amounts of columns of matrix A but I can only seem to get it to give me the sum of all positive elements of the matrix instead of each column:

```
colSumPos(A){

columns <- ncol(A)

v1 <- vector("numeric", columns)

    for(i in 1:columns)
    {
        v1[i] <- sum(A[which(A>0)])
    }
}
```

Could someone please explain how I get the sum of each column separately and then how I can simplify the code to dispose of the nested loop?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN=2` to loop through the columns and get the `sum` of elements that are greater than 0

```
apply(A, 2, function(x) sum(x[x >0], na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] 1.8036685 0.7129192 0.9305136 2.6625824 0.0000000
```

Or another option is `colSums` after replacing the values less than or equal to 0 with NA

```
colSums(A*NA^(A<=0), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 1.8036685 0.7129192 0.9305136 2.6625824 0.0000000
```

Or by more direct approach

```
colSums(replace(A, A<=0, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 1.8036685 0.7129192 0.9305136 2.6625824 0.0000000
```

Or if there are no NA elements (no need for `na.rm=TRUE`), we can replace the values that are less than or equal to 0 with 0 and make it compact (as @ikop commented)

```
colSums(A*(A>0))
#[1] 1.8036685 0.7129192 0.9305136 2.6625824 0.0000000
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
A <- matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5)
```

Comment: In the second approach, you could also just replace the negative elements with 0: `colSums(A*(A>0))`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused....which of these variants uses a nested-loop? I thought a nested loop had to use either a for or a while loop?

Comment: @sooki-sooki  Why do you want to use a nested-loop when you can do this more efficiently without a loop?

Comment: @akrun because it's unfortunately a part of the question. I must give 2 answers... one as a nested loop and the other using only matrix/vector operations. Thank you for the much more efficient code though!

Comment: @akrun I have implemented your first solution and with a small matrix it gives the correct sums. However, if I try implementing it with a 2000x2000 matrix, it gives me the sum of all its values repeated in a matrix. Do you know why this might be and how I could make it work with such a large matrix?

Comment: @sooki-sook It should work well for a 2000x2000 matrix

Comment: @sooki-sooki   `set.seed(24);
 A1 <- matrix(rnorm(2000*2000), 2000, 2000);
v1 <- colSums(A1*(A1>0));length(v1)#
[1] 2000` as you can see, it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

You try code folow if you using for loop

```
sumColum <- function(A){
for(i in 1:nrow(A)){
    for(j in 1:ncol(A)){
        colSums(replace(A, A<=0, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
    }
}
colSums(A)
```

}

Comment: This answer is great for a small matrix. However, when I apply a large (2000x2000) matrix, it gives me the sum of all the matrix elements instead of a vector with the total sum of the positive elements of each individual column. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Also, it is still suming up the negative values as well instead of turning them to zeros....?

Comment: So is there a way to calculate the sums of the positive values of the columns using nested loops within a 2000x2000 matrix?

Comment: Using a loop is slow, but it is still true